# Highlighting part of text

Tags: java, android, string

how to 'pull out' these answers so I can use them in OnClick method to highlight each of them when pressed in Android Studio?
Thanks for help.

```
<resources>
   <string name="My_dog">My dog's name is Happy. He likes to jump and sleep. Sometimes he sleeps more than he jumps :) 
        What does Happy like to do?
           1) run,
           2) swim,
           3) jump and sleep.
   </string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 1 string.  Use 1 for the question and one for each answer.  Then you don't need to pull out anything.

Comment: Great, thank you! Gabe, but than how can I connect this 'answer string' with the rest, to be able to unclick the chosen answer by clicking anywhere on the screen?